# mongoose update : $inc is not working in upsert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to update the document if exist or insert if not exist.I have one field with $inc,( want to increment previous value by one). 
My code is

```
var Appuser = new Appusers({
   imei: req.body.imei,
   $inc : {user_count:1},
   install_flag : 1
});
var upsertData = Appuser.toObject();

delete upsertData._id;

Appusers.update({imei: Appuser.imei}, upsertData, {upsert: true}, function(err, data){ 
   if(err) return console.log(err);
   res.send(data);
});
```

Only $inc is not working. In schema i have `user_count : { type:Number, default:0}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd like to suggest this:

```
Appusers.update({imei: Appuser.imei}, {$set: {imei: req.body.imei, install_flag : 1}, $inc : {user_count:1}}, {upsert: true}, function(err, data){ 
   if(err) return console.log(err);
   res.send(data);
});
```

Or If you want to use an object:

```
var upsertData = {
      $set: {imei: req.body.imei, install_flag : 1}, 
      $inc: {user_count: 1}
};

Appusers.update({imei: Appuser.imei}, upsertData, {upsert: true}, function(err, data){ 
   if(err) return console.log(err);
   res.send(data);
});
```

Comment: noooooo need to say SORRY, i am already grateful to you  for answering

Answer (score 9):

You can not increase a value when it does not exists (yet). You can use `$setOnInsert` to set *user_count* to 1 when inserting the document. Here are the docs for [$setOnInsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/).

Your query will look like this:

```
var Appuser = new Appusers({
    imei: req.body.imei,
    install_flag : 1
});

Appusers
    .update({
        imei: Appuser.imei
    }, {
        $set: upsertData,
        $setOnInsert: {
            user_count: 1
        },
        $inc: {
            user_count:1
        }
    }, {
        upsert: true
    }, function(err, data) {
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        res.send(data);
    });
```

Comment: this code will set user_count=1 on insert then how can increment the value by one on update, if $inc is not working

Comment: @AmmarHayderKhan Is $inc not working for existing documents (with your code)?

Comment: @AmmarHayderKhan Hmm. Strange. Can you try my updated answer?

Comment: Why was this down voted? What is wrong with my answer?

Comment: The answer is not correct as Mongoose doesn't allow to combine $setOnInsert and $inc for the same field. You'll receive the following error: `MongoError: Cannot update 'user_count' and 'user_count' at the same time`. It seems that $inc on a non-existing document will assign the value of increment to the field, so no need to use $setOnInsert in this case.