# Mongoose throwing You must specify a field error while using a variable at place of an explicit string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**My Mongoose Command**

```
    Modelname.update(
        {$and :[ {'field1' : field1}, {'field2' : field2}, {'field3' : field3}, {'field4' : field4}]},
        {
            $set : {'timestamp' : timestamp},
            $inc : {speed_string: 1}
        },{upsert: true}, function (err, record)
        {
            if (err)
            {

            }
            else
            {

            }
        });
```

As you can see that speed_string is a variable which is supposed to get increased in the real document or get upserted . I have logged it just before the query and it is indeed a string (and not empty like the error reads) but the query is not going through and I am getting this error.

> "errmsg":"'$inc' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$inc:
>   {: ...}}"}

When I am replacing that variable with `'expected_string'` things are working fine and that is more confusing, nevertheless.

There is something I am doing wrong, help is appreciated.

Comment: I also noticed that problem. Field index must be a string like `{'speed_string': 1}`

Comment: @PavloZhukov Thank you for your time Pavlo. There has to be some way for this... things work just fine in case of pymongo for python in similar case.

Comment: And [API](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) tells it must work, but on practice on Node.js it works only if it setted as string. I was confuse by it too

Comment: Damn this. I even tried this `var string = "'" +  speed_string + "'";` which gives you 'stringvalue', still not working @PavloZhukov

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197885/mongoose-update-inc-is-not-working-in-upsert) I fixed that in similar way on MongoDB 2.6

Comment: @JohnnyHK Damn! It Worked _/\_ How?

Comment: @PavloZhukov Thanks for your time and help mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a variable as a field name, you need to use the [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) syntax where the variable is enclosed in square brackets:

```
Modelname.update(
    {$and :[ {'field1' : field1}, {'field2' : field2}, {'field3' : field3}, {'field4' : field4}]},
    {
        $set : {'timestamp' : timestamp},
        $inc : {[speed_string]: 1}
    },{upsert: true}, function (err, record)
    {
        ...
    });
```

Also, multiple terms in a query are implicitly ANDed, so you can simplify your query object to:

```
Modelname.update(
    {
        'field1' : field1, 
        'field2' : field2,
        'field3' : field3,
        'field4' : field4
    },
    {
        $set : {'timestamp' : timestamp},
        $inc : {[speed_string]: 1}
    },{upsert: true}, function (err, record)
    {
        ...
    });
```

Comment: I am aware about the second part just went ahead with it. Thanks man.