# Mongoose $inc ( increment ) not working for some options in schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

My mongoose schema -

```
const { model, Schema } = require('mongoose');

module.exports = model(
  'Collectibles',
  new Schema({
    userId: String,
    guildId: String,
    candles: Number,
    skulls: Number,
    daggers: Number,
    spiders: Number,
    masks: Number,
    witchhat: Number,
    witchbroom: Number,
    witchcrystal: Number,
    groovyghost: Number,
    groovymic: Number,
    groovyspeakers: Number,
    vampirefangs: Number,
    vampirebat: Number,
    vampirecape: Number,
    zombieblood: Number,
    zombieteeth: Number,
    zombieeye: Number,
    grimskull: Number,
    grimscythe: Number,
    grimhood: Number,
    commonpack: Boolean,
    witchpack: Boolean,
    groovypack: Boolean,
    vampirepack: Boolean,
    zombiepack: Boolean,
    grimpack: Boolean,
  })
);
```

Increment code -

```
await Collectibles.updateOne(
        { userId: i.user.id },
        { $inc: { witchhat: 1 } }
      )
```

The increment not works on any options after masks
I have tried using increment on all options till masks it works but not on anything below it
and btw i.user.id is a unique id

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongoose update : $inc is not working in upsert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197885/mongoose-update-inc-is-not-working-in-upsert)

Comment: @CharchitKapoor No i'hv already set the value to 0

Comment: give one sample document @ASTREX

Comment: @nodejsdeveloper wdym by a sample document ?

Comment: If the value is already 0, then the filter part is not matching any document

Comment: If you mean how im already saving the value to 0 then here - https://pastebin.com/XRsgApvr

Comment: @CharchitKapoor which filter part ?

Answer (score 1):

check this out bro it's working fine

> https://mongoplayground.net/p/xgyKIiyTRrX

Comment: check that ur passing id in the filter's are right one

Comment: im pretty confused as well im literally using the same code

Comment: it is right because when im using on options above masks its working fine

Comment: console the value (i.user.id) and check if it's working or not

Comment: yes checked its same